# Swift2. 配列を削除するremoveAtIndex()について質問です

Tags: swift, swift2, spritekit

早速質問なのですが、今現在簡単な間違い探しの様なゲームを作成しようとしています。
内容としては、正方形を同じ形で色を付けて４つ表示し、１つだけ違う色で表示するというものです。

そこでいくつもの問題を作り（赤色、黄色、青など）ランダムに表示させた後に
１回選ばれた問題を削除する（配列から削除し、次回から表示させない）用にしたいのですが
うまくその問題が削除されずに、また表示されてしまいます。
コードは以下になります。

コードの問題があると思う所は、「問題をランダムに選んでその後削除する」になります。
よろしくお願いします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```swift
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    //問題設定
    let randomSource = GKARC4RandomSource()
    var questionMax:Int = 6
    var questionList:[SKShapeNode] = []
    let correct = ["■"]
    let mistake = ["■"]
    var questionNo:Int = 0
    var misutakeNo:Int = 0

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        //問題実行
        questioning()
    }

    //問題をランダムで選んでその後削除する
    func questioning(){
        var items = [newQuestion, newQuestion2]
        let q1 = Int(arc4random()) % items.count
        items[q1]()
        let _ = items.removeAtIndex(q1)
    }

    //問題設定１青
    func newQuestion(){
        questionMax = 4
        questionNo = randomSource.nextIntWithUpperBound(correct.count)
        misutakeNo = randomSource.nextIntWithUpperBound(questionMax)
        questionList = []

        for LoopID in 0..<questionMax {
            let question = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize:CGSizeMake(308.0,308.0))
            let x = (LoopID % 2) * 315 + 165
            let y = (LoopID / 2) * 315 + 470
            question.position = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
            self.addChild(question)
            questionList.append(question)

            let sikisai = SKLabelNode()

            if LoopID != misutakeNo {
                sikisai.text = correct[questionNo]
                sikisai.fontColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 0/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1.0)
            }else {
                sikisai.text = mistake[questionNo]
                sikisai.fontColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 0/255, blue: 100/255, alpha: 1.0)
            }

            sikisai.fontSize = 405
            sikisai.position = CGPoint(x:0, y:-155)
            question.addChild(sikisai)
        }
    }

    //問題設定2赤
    func newQuestion2(){
        questionMax = 4
        questionNo = randomSource.nextIntWithUpperBound(correct.count)
        misutakeNo = randomSource.nextIntWithUpperBound(questionMax)
        questionList = []

        for LoopID in 0..<questionMax {
            let question = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize:CGSizeMake(308.0,308.0))
            let x = (LoopID % 2) * 315 + 165
            let y = (LoopID / 2) * 315 + 470
            question.position = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
            self.addChild(question)
            questionList.append(question)

            let sikisai = SKLabelNode()

            if LoopID != misutakeNo {
                sikisai.text = correct[questionNo]
                sikisai.fontColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 0/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1.0)
            }else {
                sikisai.text = mistake[questionNo]
                sikisai.fontColor = UIColor(red: 100/255, green: 0/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1.0)
            }

            sikisai.fontSize = 405
            sikisai.position = CGPoint(x:0, y:-155)
            question.addChild(sikisai)
        }
    }

    //タップを調べる
    func answerCheck(NO:Int) {
        if NO == misutakeNo {
            //正解
            questioning()
        } else {
            //不正解
            questioning()
        }

        for LoopID in 0..<questionMax {
            questionList[LoopID].removeFromParent()
            questioning()}
        }

    //タップ処理
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            let touchNodes = self.nodesAtPoint(location)

            for tNode in touchNodes {
                for LoopID in 0..<questionMax {
                    if tNode == questionList[LoopID]{
                        answerCheck(LoopID)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: コードを挿入されるときは {} アイコンの機能をうまく使って、綺麗に成形していただくと読みやすくなります。示されたコードにあるremoveAtIndexが呼ばれている対象は、questioning()メソッドのローカル変数ですので、questioning()メソッドの終了後はなくなってしまいますから、「うまく削除されません」がどういうことを表しているのかよくわかりません。どんな動作を期待したのに、実際の動作はどうだったのか、を記載してください。エラーメッセージやアウトプットがログに残せるのならそちらの記録を示していただくのも解決のお役に立つかもしれません。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
読みにくくコードを書いてしまいすみません。

期待している動作は、
間違い探しゲームのような形で
newQuestion1は赤い四角の正方形4つを表示しその内の1つを違う色で表示する。
newQuestion2は同じ形で青。
newQuestion3は黄色です。
そして、ランダムで色のついた四角を表示し、赤色の四角の問題が出てきたら、次にその赤色の四角が出ないように削除。そして、次は青か黄色の問題を表示。といった動作にしたいです。

今のままだと、その問題が削除されず、同じ問題が何回も選ばれてしまいます。
エラーは表示されません。

説明が足りない所があると思いますが、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score -1, accepted):

いただいたコメントと修正後のご質問に合わせてコードを修正しました。(なかなか難しいことをやろうとしているようなので、正直あなたの意図を理解できている自信はないのですが。)

あなたは、questioning()メソッドの中で

```
var items = [newQuestion,newQuestion2]
```

という宣言をしています。つまりquestioning()メソッドを呼ぶたびに毎回毎回全部の問題が入った配列をitemsに設定しなおしているわけです。残りの行でitemsの中の問題を乱数で均一に(厳密に言うと均一ではないのですが、クイズアプリを作るなら全く問題にならない誤差です)選んでいるのですから、同じ問題が何度も出題されることがあっても当然と言うことになります。

もしメソッドが終了した後も状態を覚えさせておきたいのだとしたら、メソッドのローカル変数にそのような状態を入れても意味がありません。コメントにも書きましたようにメソッドのローカル変数というのは、メソッドの実行が終了したら消えてしまいます。(あなたのコードの場合、毎回そのローカル変数に値を入れ直しているので、消えてしまうどころか、「何も削除されていない」ように見えるわけです。)

いつ元の状態にリセットするのか、という点はよく考えないといけませんが、そのような状態を表すための変数は、通常インスタンス変数(Swiftならインスタンスプロパティ)にします。
ただし、Swiftではインスタンス変数の初期化に使う式は特殊なコンテキストで解釈されるので、変数の宣言と変数への値の設定は分けるという(直感からすると)変則的な書き方になります。

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    //インスタンスプロパティはclassの内側、すべてのメソッドの外側に宣言する
    var items: [()->Void] = []
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        //メソッドをクロージャとして使うのは、インスタンスのコンテキストでないといけない
        items = [newQuestion, newQuestion2]
        //問題実行
        questioning()
    }
    func questioning(){
        let q1 = Int(arc4random()) % items.count

        //問題を出す
        items[q1]()
        //選ばれた問題を削除
        items.removeAtIndex(q1)
        //↑このitemsはインスタンスプロパティなので、「削除」された状態をインスタンスが存在する限り覚えている
    }

    func newQuestion(){
        //...
    }

    func newQuestion2(){
        //...
    }
}
```

ただし、このコードには問題があります。それはSwiftのメソッドをクロージャーとして使った場合、必ずselfが強参照としてクロージャー内に保持されることで、それをさらにselfのプロパティに放り込んでしまうと、循環参照が生じて、メモリリークの原因になります。

少し回りくどく、「本当にやりたいこと」が見えにくくなってしまうのですが、例えば次のようなコードに書き直す必要があるでしょう。

```
enum QuestionItem {
    case Q1, Q2, Q3
}
extension QuestionItem {
    func question(object: GameScene) {
        switch self {
        case Q1:
            object.newQuestion1()
        case Q2:
            object.newQuestion2()
        case Q3:
            object.newQuestion3()
        }
    }
}
class GameScene: SKScene {
    //インスタンスプロパティはclassの内側、すべてのメソッドの外側に宣言する
    var items: [QuestionItem] = [.Q1, .Q2, .Q3]
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        //問題実行
        questioning()
    }
    func questioning(){
        if items.count == 0 {
            /* itemsが空の時の処理 */
        }
        let q1 = Int(arc4random()) % items.count

        //問題を出す
        items[q1].question(self)
        //選ばれた問題を削除
        items.removeAtIndex(q1)
        //↑このitemsはインスタンスプロパティなので、「削除」された状態をインスタンスが存在する限り覚えている
    }

    func newQuestion1(){
        //...
    }

    func newQuestion2(){
        //...
    }

    func newQuestion3(){
        //...
    }
}
```

少々厄介な問題が絡んでしまいましたが、いかがでしょうか。何かお気付きの点がありましたら、またコメント等でお知らせください。

Comment: 大変失礼しました。質問をする立場として、回答をして頂く為に最低限 私達ができる事は分かりやすく書く事でした・・・　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　 　　 もっと基礎等をしっかりと学びたいと思います。 ご回答ありがとうございます。 インスタンスプロパティに書いてみたのですが、ここでエラーが表示されるようになってしまいました。 エラーが表示される場所は、 func questioning(){ let q1 = Int(arc4random()) % items.count items[q1]() let _ = items.removeAtIndex(q1) } のitems[q1]()　所に Cannot invoke value of type "GameScene -> () ->" with argument list "()" と表示されます。 メソッドの戻り値に原因があると書いてありましたが、このような場合はVoidを入れるのでしょうか？
 何度も重ねて質問をしてしまい、本当にすみません。 お時間がある時でよろしいのでよろしくお願いします。

Comment: 厳しいダメ出しをするのはこのサイトをより良いQAの場所としたいからですので、私的にはご丁寧な謝罪の言葉をいただくよりも、少しでも元のご質問を改善しようと努力していただいたことの方が嬉しいです。その意味でも、回答の方にわかりにくい点や不十分だった点があればどしどしとご指摘いただけると助かります。さて、本題の方ですが、私が提示したコードはnewQuestion1,...をメソッドではなく、グローバル関数と仮定して作成してありましたので、あなたの改善後のコードのようにメソッドだったとすると、ご指摘のような意味不明の(私的には意味不明ではないのですが、説明するとかなり長くなります)エラーが出ることになります。後ほど回答を編集して修正版のコードを掲載しますので、お試しください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
お時間がある時にいつでもよろしいので、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 回答あがとうございます。
丁寧なコードまで本当にありがとうございます。
しかし、同じコードでやってみてもエラーになってしまいます。
画像を添付しました。
アプリは通常に起動するのですが、タップした時にクラッシュしてしまいます。items.removeAtIndex(q1)を処理する際にクラッシュをしていると思うのですが、何故でしょうか？

Comment: 添付いただいた写真ではEXC_BREAKPOINTと表示されており、2行ほど下にブレークポイントのマーカーがあること、デバッグ領域に変数値が表示されていることなどから、ブレークポイントで停止している状態に見えます。停止している行とブレークポイントのマーカーがずれていますので、何か別の原因で変なことが起こっている可能性もありますが、とりあえずすべてのブレークポイントを削除してクリーンビルドした上で再度おためしください。

Comment: 全てブレークポイント削除してもやはりダメでした・・・
他に原因は何か考えられるでしょうか？

Comment: ブレークポイント以外が原因ということで、あなたが現在ご質問に挙げられているコードと私の回答のコードを混ぜて試してみたところ、EXC_BREAKPOINTではなく、EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTIONと言う実行時エラーが同じ行で発生しました。Xcodeの状態か設定が異なっているのかもしれません。原因は、あなたのanswerCheck()メソッドの中でquestioning()を複数回呼んでいるため、その度にitems要素が減っていき、items.countが0になってから呼ばれた時に`Int(arc4random()) % items.count`が0除算の例外を起こしているせいでした。ここから先は「本当は何をどうしたいのか」をもう少しうまく伝えていただかないとなんとも言えませんが、少なくとも、処理の途中でitemsが空になったらどうするのか決めて、空の時にはquestioning()を呼ばれないようにする、といった対策が必要でしょう。

Comment: すみません。私が最初に明確に何をしたいかを記載していない為、色々と質問の方向性が変わってしまい、申し訳いです。しかしこの問題が解決すれば、私がやりたかった事です‌​。なるほど、それでクラッシュを起こしていたのですね。最終的には、問題を繰り返したいと思っています。 itemsが空になったら次の設問に移行したいです。（今itemsに準備しているのがQ1.Q2.Q3です。itemsが空になったら(仮にitems2)に(Q4.Q‌​5.Q6を準備する)items空→items2。その場合itemsが空になった時の処理を書きたのですが、どうすれば、itemsが空になった事を知れるのでしょうか？

Comment: 確実な方法は「0になっては困る場所の前でチェックする」ことで、`let q1 = Int(arc4random()) % items.count`の前に`if items.count == 0 {/* itemsが空の時の処理 */}`というチェックコードを置くことでしょう。(isEmptyなるメソッドがあって、世間的には空かどうかのチェックにはそちらが推奨されていますが、次の行で`count`を使っているので、わかりやすさを優先しました。)

Comment: エラー無く上手くできました！私一人では絶対に解決できる事は無かったと思います。挫折する一歩手前で Le Père d'OO さんに質問をさせて頂いて、本当に分かりやすく、凄く丁寧にコードまで書いて頂いて。私にとって今が人生の分岐点と言っても過言では無いです。今回でとても色々学ぶ事ができました。これからはもっと本などにも目を等して基礎もしっかりと学びたいと思います。本当に本当にありがとうございました。